# connect to netconf server using python

Tags: python, server, client, netconf

getting this error SSHError("Could not open connection, possibly due to unacceptable"
ncclient.transport.errors.SSHError: Could not open connection, possibly due to unacceptable SSH subsystem name.
i am using nccliet library
code is from ncclient import manager

```
# Connect to the Netopeer server
with manager.connect(
        host="192.168.3.253",
        port=22,
        username="root",
        password="root",
        device_params={'name': 'default'},
        hostkey_verify=False,
        allow_agent=False,
        look_for_keys=False) as m:

    # Lock the configuration datastore
    m.lock('running')

    # Edit the configuration
    config = '''
    <config xmlns:sys="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-system">
        <sys:system>
            <sys:hostname>my-hostname</sys:hostname>
        </sys:system>
    </config>
    '''
    m.edit_config(target='running', config=config)

    # Unlock the configuration datastore
    m.unlock('running')
```

also tried adding         ssh_subsystem_name='netconf' it gave error TypeError: SSHSession.connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssh_subsystem_name'